# Forecast.io Ruby Gem - Remove Decimal from Temperature

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I am using the [forecast-ruby](https://github.com/darkskyapp/forecast-ruby) gem and everything is working fine.  However, when you get the temperature from the API, it returns it with decimals, which I don't need.  (e.g., 85.23).  I would like to strip the last 2 digits and just display the temperature as 85 degrees.

Here is what I am working with:

`@forecast = ForecastIO.forecast(lat, long)`

Then, I can check the current temp with: `@forecast.currently.temperature` => 85.23

Does anyone know of a way to either request just the basic temperature from the API? If not, how would I go about removing the last three characters within the method above to achieve an end result of just `85`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that you're not dealing with characters, it's a number, so just use `.round`:

```
x = 85.23
x.round # 85
```

If you want to actually truncate to 85 (even if the temperature were say 85.99) then use `.to_i` instead.

Comment: That's it.  Thanks @meagar.  I can accept your answer in 5 min.  Still learning Ruby, and I forget about a lot of its simplicity.